# Starting SonarQube in my remote linux ubuntu machine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

I'm trying to start SonarQube in my linux machine, but i'm getting this error:

```
--> Wrapper Started as Daemon
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2017.03.28 20:00:24 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonar/temp
2017.03.28 20:00:24 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[es]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djna.nosys=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonar/temp -javaagent:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer /opt/sonar/temp/sq-process4414918112205828016properties
2017.03.28 20:00:25 INFO   es[][o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint]  Starting es
2017.03.28 20:00:25 INFO   es[][o.s.s.EsSettings]  Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
2017.03.28 20:00:26 INFO   es[][o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonarqube] version[2.3.3], pid[4801], build[218bdf1/2016-05-17T15:40:04Z]
2017.03.28 20:00:26 INFO   es[][o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonarqube] initializing ...
2017.03.28 20:00:26 INFO   es[][o.e.plugins]  [sonarqube] modules [], plugins [], sites []
2017.03.28 20:00:26 INFO   es[][o.elasticsearch.env]  [sonarqube] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (/dev/root)]], net usable_space [12.5gb], net total_space [19.4gb], spins? [possibly], types [ext4]
2017.03.28 20:00:26 INFO   es[][o.elasticsearch.env]  [sonarqube] heap size [1015.6mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
2017.03.28 20:00:30 INFO   es[][o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonarqube] initialized
2017.03.28 20:00:30 INFO   es[][o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonarqube] starting ...
2017.03.28 20:00:30 INFO   es[][o.e.transport]  [sonarqube] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9001}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9001}
2017.03.28 20:00:30 INFO   es[][o.e.discovery]  [sonarqube] sonarqube/upk_GmJgQPmBqNGykii2jw
2017.03.28 20:00:33 INFO   es[][o.e.cluster.service]  [sonarqube] new_master {sonarqube}{upk_GmJgQPmBqNGykii2jw}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9001}{rack_id=sonarqube, master=true}, reason: zen-disco-join(elected_as_master, [0] joins received)
2017.03.28 20:00:33 INFO   es[][o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonarqube] started
2017.03.28 20:00:33 INFO   es[][o.e.gateway]  [sonarqube] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
2017.03.28 20:00:33 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is up
2017.03.28 20:00:33 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[web]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djruby.management.enabled=false -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=false -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonar/temp -javaagent:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/server/*:/opt/sonar/lib/jdbc/mysql/mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer /opt/sonar/temp/sq-process3450868362392661343properties
2017.03.28 20:00:34 INFO  web[][o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Starting web
2017.03.28 20:00:35 INFO  web[][o.s.s.a.TomcatContexts] Webapp directory: /opt/sonar/web
2017.03.28 20:00:35 INFO  web[][o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-127.0.0.1-9000"]
2017.03.28 20:00:35 INFO  web[][o.a.t.u.n.NioSelectorPool] Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
2017.03.28 20:00:36 INFO  web[][o.e.plugins] [Eternal Brain] modules [], plugins [], sites []
2017.03.28 20:00:38 INFO  web[][o.s.s.e.EsClientProvider] Connected to local Elasticsearch: [127.0.0.1:9001]
2017.03.28 20:00:38 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.LogServerVersion] SonarQube Server / 6.1 / dc148a71a1c184ccad588b66251980c994879dff
2017.03.28 20:00:38 INFO  web[][o.sonar.db.Database] Create JDBC data source for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance
Tue Mar 28 20:00:38 UTC 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Tue Mar 28 20:00:38 UTC 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
2017.03.28 20:00:40 ERROR web[][o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/sonar]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.sonar.server.platform.web.PlatformServletContextListener
org.sonar.api.utils.MessageException: Database was upgraded to a more recent of SonarQube. Backup must probably be restored or db settings are incorrect.
2017.03.28 20:00:40 ERROR web[][o.a.c.c.StandardContext] One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
2017.03.28 20:00:40 ERROR web[][o.a.c.c.StandardContext] Context [/sonar] startup failed due to previous errors
2017.03.28 20:00:40 WARN  web[][o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoaderBase] The web application [sonar] appears to have started a thread named [elasticsearch[Eternal Brain][[timer]]] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
 org.elasticsearch.threadpool.ThreadPool$EstimatedTimeThread.run(ThreadPool.java:719)
2017.03.28 20:00:40 WARN  web[][o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoaderBase] The web application [sonar] appears to have started a thread named [elasticsearch[Eternal Brain][scheduler][T#1]] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
 java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093)
 java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2017.03.28 20:00:40 WARN  web[][o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoaderBase] The web application [sonar] appears to have started a thread named [elasticsearch[Eternal Brain][transport_client_worker][T#1]{New I/O worker #1}] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
 sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
 sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.SelectorUtil.select(SelectorUtil.java:68)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.select(AbstractNioSelector.java:434)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:212)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
 org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
 org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2017.03.28 20:00:40 WARN  web[][o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoaderBase] The web application [sonar] appears to have started a thread named [elasticsearch[Eternal Brain][transport_client_worker][T#2]{New I/O worker #2}] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
 sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
 sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.SelectorUtil.select(SelectorUtil.java:68)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.select(AbstractNioSelector.java:434)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:212)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
 org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
 org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2017.03.28 20:00:40 WARN  web[][o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoaderBase] The web application [sonar] appears to have started a thread named [elasticsearch[Eternal Brain][transport_client_boss][T#1]{New I/O boss #3}] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
 sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
 sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.SelectorUtil.select(SelectorUtil.java:68)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.select(AbstractNioSelector.java:434)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:212)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.run(NioClientBoss.java:42)
 org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
 org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2017.03.28 20:00:40 WARN  web[][o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoaderBase] The web application [sonar] appears to have started a thread named [elasticsearch[Eternal Brain][transport_client_timer][T#1]{Hashed wheel timer #1}] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
 org.jboss.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$Worker.waitForNextTick(HashedWheelTimer.java:445)
 org.jboss.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$Worker.run(HashedWheelTimer.java:364)
 org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2017.03.28 20:00:40 WARN  web[][o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoaderBase] The web application [sonar] appears to have started a thread named [elasticsearch[Eternal Brain][generic][T#1]] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
 java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:460)
 java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:362)
 java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:941)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1066)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2017.03.28 20:00:40 WARN  web[][o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoaderBase] The web application [sonar] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
 com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:43)
2017.03.28 20:00:40 WARN  web[][o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoaderBase] The web application [sonar] appears to have started a thread named [Timer-0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:552)
 java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
2017.03.28 20:00:40 INFO  web[][o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-127.0.0.1-9000"]
2017.03.28 20:00:40 INFO  web[][o.s.s.a.TomcatAccessLog] Web server is started
2017.03.28 20:00:40 INFO  web[][o.s.s.a.EmbeddedTomcat] HTTP connector enabled on port 9000
2017.03.28 20:00:40 WARN  web[][o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Fail to start web
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Webapp did not start
    at org.sonar.server.app.EmbeddedTomcat.isUp(EmbeddedTomcat.java:84) ~[sonar-server-6.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.isUp(WebServer.java:46) [sonar-server-6.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:105) ~[sonar-process-6.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.main(WebServer.java:67) [sonar-server-6.1.jar:na]
2017.03.28 20:00:40 INFO  web[][o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-127.0.0.1-9000"]
2017.03.28 20:00:41 INFO  web[][o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-127.0.0.1-9000"]
2017.03.28 20:00:42 INFO  web[][o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-127.0.0.1-9000"]
2017.03.28 20:00:42 INFO  web[][o.s.s.a.TomcatAccessLog] Web server is stopped
2017.03.28 20:00:42 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is stopping
2017.03.28 20:00:42 INFO   es[][o.s.p.StopWatcher]  Stopping process
2017.03.28 20:00:42 INFO   es[][o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonarqube] stopping ...
2017.03.28 20:00:42 INFO   es[][o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonarqube] stopped
2017.03.28 20:00:42 INFO   es[][o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonarqube] closing ...
2017.03.28 20:00:42 INFO   es[][o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonarqube] closed
2017.03.28 20:00:43 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is stopped
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

the log show me that it's a memory leak, but i don't think that is the error cause.

I was reading in some posts that it's cause because the java isn't reconized.

Comment: Could you attach the full logs please?

Comment: I edited the question and i attached the full log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error "Database was upgraded to a more recent of SonarQube. Backup must probably be restored or db settings are incorrect." means that the DB schema has already been used by another version of SonarQube (> 6.1 in your case).

You should re-create the schema or install the correct version of SonarQube.